# AngularJS: What is a modular approach to sidebars and sub-pages?

Tags: angularjs

I'm building an app for fun and practice, and within the app there is a dashboard module. That dashboard module houses other modules. I do this because the dashboard is the parent state for the modules inside of it and I didn't think it would be right to put them in the outside folder with all the other irrelevent modules, because they belong to the dashboard. For example:

```
/login
/signup
/logout
/profile
/dashboard
    /home
    /settings
    /foo
    /bar
```

...and their states would be `dashboard.home` with a url of `/dashboard/home`, and so forth.

In the settings folder, I have a current set up that works, but I don't know if it's considered good practice.

Under the settings directory, I have some partials and controllers. For example:

```
/login
/signup
/logout
/profile
/dashboard
    /home
    /settings
        /controllers
            settingsAccount.controller.js
            settingsPassword.controller.js
            settingsPersonal.controller.js
        /partials
            _account.html
            _password.html
            _personal.html
        settings.html
        settings.module.js
    /foo
    /bar
```

And those partials would be navigated through on the settings.html. How I currently do this is like this..

**settings.html:**

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="LeftSidebarController as sidebar">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="page-title">
            <h1 view-title>Settings</h1>
        </div>

        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-class="{'active': sidebar.currentTab(1)}" ng-click="sidebar.setTab(1)">
                <a href>Account</a> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right list-group-item__arrow-right"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-class="{'active': sidebar.currentTab(2)}" ng-click="sidebar.setTab(2)">
                <a href>Password</a> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right list-group-item__arrow-right"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-class="{'active': sidebar.currentTab(3)}" ng-click="sidebar.setTab(3)">
                <a href>Personal</a> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right list-group-item__arrow-right"></i>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="widget-container widget-container--settings fluid-height">
            <div ng-if="sidebar.currentTab(1)"
                 ng-include src="'app/dashboard/settings/partials/_account.html'"
                 ng-controller="SettingsAccountController as account"></div>

            <div ng-if="sidebar.currentTab(2)"
                 ng-include src="'app/dashboard/settings/partials/_password.html'"
                 ng-controller="SettingsPasswordController as password"></div>

            <div ng-if="sidebar.currentTab(3)"
                 ng-include src="'app/dashboard/settings/partials/_personal.html'"
                 ng-controller="SettingsPersonalController as personal"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and I have a global controller **LeftSidebarController**, which looks like this:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.controllers')
        .controller('LeftSidebarController', LeftSidebarController);

    function LeftSidebarController() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.tab = 1;

        vm.setTab = function(tabId) {
            vm.tab = tabId;
        };

        vm.currentTab = function(tabId) {
            return vm.tab === tabId;
        };
    }

})();
```

So as you can see, I basically just load one of the partials and attach it's controller to it based on which tab is clicked in the sidebar.

Has anyone ever had to do something like this and know a better approach? I'd really appreciate some good guidance, I don't want to make it like this because it seems really messy to me.

I thought having the sub-sub-modules, with a state of something like  `dashboard.settings.account`, with url of `/dashboard/settings/account`. If I can't find a better approach I'll probably go that route, seems a bit better to me because then everything has it's own state and I will no longer be including multiple files and controllers in a single state. Only problem is I don't know how I'd handle the sidebar yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a [routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) where you can define a contoller and a templates for every of your routes?

Comment: This question invites a lot of opinionated answers, but a lot of people follow this style guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/README.md#folders-by-feature-structure

Comment: @65756C626F74 I am already using ui-router. These "sub-views" in the settings state are not states themselves, they are just sort of "hide/show" content based on what you click. Might have to make them into states like what I mentioned at the end of my post.. that'll resolve this mess. I'll just how to find a way to make the sidebar modular and reuseable then.

Comment: @Shaun Scovil I am actually following that on everything I build, my codebased is completely synchronous with it except for the fact that it doesn't show examples for what I'm trying to do. Their examples only go one directory deep and Im in 3-4 layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I build an app using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), I usually structure it this way:

```
/app
  /components
  /states
    /login
    /signup
    /logout
    /profile
    /dashboard
    states.module.js
  index.html
  app.module.js
  app.config.js
```

The `components` folder is where I put all of my custom directives, services, filters, etc. organized by feature. For example, I might have a `notifications` sub-folder that contains a service and a directive.

My `states` folder has a file called `states.module.js` that would look something like this:

```
angular.module('app.states', [
  'app.states.login',
  'app.states.signup',
  'app.states.logout',
  // etc.
]);
```

Then each state sub-folder would have a module and all of the files associated with that state. It would also have a `{state}.config.js` file that adds the state to `$stateProvider`.

All of that is similar to what you have done (though I wouldn't put controllers and templates in separate folders). The key difference is, in the case of your dashboard state, I would use views.

**dashboard.config.js**

```
angular.module('app.states.dashboard')
  .config(stateConfig)
;

function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard/:view',
      views: {
        'home@dashboard': {
          controller  : 'DashboardHomeViewController',
          controllerAs: 'home',
          templateUrl : 'states/dashboard/home.html'
        },
        'settings@dashboard': {
          controller  : 'DashboardSettingsViewController',
          controllerAs: 'settings',
          templateUrl : 'states/dashboard/settings.html'
        },
        '': {
          controller  : 'DashboardViewController',
          controllerAs: 'dashboard',
          templateUrl : 'states/dashboard/dashboard.html'
        },
      }
    )
  ;
}
```

I would have files in that folder for each view controller and template, as well as a module file. The main view template file would look something like this:

**dashboard.html**

```
<ui-view name="{{dashboard.view}}@dashboard"></ui-view>
```

Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: I think something like this may be what i'm looking for, except for the fact that the problem is within the views that are in the settings of the dashboard, not the views within the dashboard itself. for example, the dashboard has certain child states (home, settings, etc.). Now within the settings child state, there are even more child states. I think I can implement what you showed but in the settings.module.js..

Comment: Yeah, if a view is so complex that it has multiple views, I would make it a child state.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have views like "settings.foo@dashboard", "settings.bar@dashboard", etc. but I would question my architecture if I found myself doing that.

Comment: I'm having a bit of troubles implementing this.. can you look at this code? I'll show you everything (related) starting from the dashboard so you understand how I'm doing this. Here is the dashboard.module.js: http://laravel.io/bin/eDbXm - dashboard.html: http://laravel.io/bin/Mk7DN - settings.module.js: http://laravel.io/bin/xKEq4 - settings.html: http://laravel.io/bin/Kkjr8 -- so as you can see, dashboard is the main state. Within dashboard, there are child states that live in the ui-view="content". Within that, (settings, for example), three are more child states, in settings.module.js

Comment: When I'm on the settings, however, the account@settings, password@settings, etc do not show even if I  remove the ng-if. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you go to github.com and go to any repo, notice how they have the horizontal navbar under the repo name? Those are like child-views of the repo. So you can click on code/issues/pull requests, etc., and it will just add /issues, /pull-requests, etc to the url on top of the state you are one, which would be the repo name. That is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Sounds awesome. Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: I just had a minute to look at the code you shared and I think I see a couple of problems. First, I'm pretty sure the ui-view directive takes a name attribute, so <div ui-view name="content"> instead of <div ui-view="content">. (Maybe you can do it either way, not sure.) Second, when referencing a view of the current state, as you are doing in settings.html, include the @view part. So <ui-view name="account@settings">.

Comment: It works now, great. Thanks again. One more thing.. I tried following your example exactly because I want to add the url of the grandchild view to the browser as opposed to just showing it anonymously, and I get errors. Sec I'll show you what I'm getting.. something about transclusion.

Comment: The code: http://laravel.io/bin/PXNnz - the error: http://laravel.io/bin/42lJa -- any idea? I am probably overcomplicating this.. I just want to have a dashboard state that houses other states such as home, settings, etc. Within those child state, their may be grandchild states. And I want to show the grandchild states in the url as well. So it'd be like 'dashboard/settings/password' instead of just 'dashboard/settings' and having the ui-view toggle based on what is clicked -- which is how it is with the fix you helped me with and how it was when I asked my question :P

Comment: Yeah, sorry the error you were seeing was caused by `ng-switch-default` and `ui-view` being used on the same element. I changed my answer to just use `ng-switch-when`...if you wanted to use `ng-switch-default` it would have to be on a wrapper element, like a div outside of your ui-view element.

Comment: Hmm removing that didn't seem to make a difference, looks like it doesnt like ui-view and ng-switch-when in the same element either.

Comment: I found a way to achieve this. Looks pretty dirty... but it works just how I want it to. Highly doubt it follows best practices though. And theres no default so thats a problem.

Comment: Use ng-if, or see if you can use an {{expression}} in the ui-view name attribute. I'm not able to test and haven't used ui-router in a while so I'm a little rusty. :-)

Comment: Yeah theres just too many ways to do this lol and I'm the kind of person that always tries to do it the best way I can so I don't have to come back later and fix it. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.